# Best toolchain for recording kinect data and converting to pointcloud offline?

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to save raw kinect data with minimal computer overhead to achieve maximal framerate on a computer that may not have enough performance for much else, and then take the saved data and do the depth-rgb alignment and conversion to point cloud non-real-time.

What tools and commands should I use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9567/best-toolchain-for-recording-kinect-data-and-converting-to-pointcloud-offline?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2011-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found some discussion of the same question here: http://kinect-with-ros.976505.n3.nabble.com/Ros-kinect-Point-cloud-projection-in-a-second-pass-for-CPU-limited-systems-td2497149.html#a2756101

When I get a chance to try it out I'd like to produce a tutorial with every command line documented, unless someone else beats me to it.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[dynamic reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) lets you turn off registration of the two images. Then you can use [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/) to save the rgb and depth image topics for later processing. Or you could edit openni_node.cpp in the openni_camera package to store the images instead of publishing, but this is far more involved.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2